# PHP Selenium Blocked by CORS Policy

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access a website with selenium and i am getting below error

[image]

And i used the following code i have tried `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` but did't work for me

```
require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";    
$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost",4444);
//$ffprofile = $webdriver->prepareBrowserProfile("");
$webdriver->connect("chrome");                            
$webdriver->get("https://healofy.com/"); sleep(3); 
$element=$webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::id,"Baby_1_2_years");
if($element) {
    print_r($element);
    $element->click();
}
```

Comment: are you using old `php-webdriver-bindings` ?

Comment: sorry sir i could not get you ,actully am totally new in this  could you please explain what you want to say ,i learnt it recently from some tutorials so if you could do it with php this will be a great help thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be you're using old [php webdriver client](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-webdriver-bindings/) (2013) ? which is not compatible with current selenium and browser.

use updated PHP selenium [facebook/webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) and here the setup step:

```
# if you have composer
composer require facebook/webdriver

# if not download composer.phar
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar require facebook/webdriver
```

read the github page above if it missing something.

and PHP code

```
<?php
namespace Facebook\WebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);

$driver->get("https://healofy.com/"); 

$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//label[@for="Baby_1_2_years"]'))->click();
//$driver->quit();

?>
```

Comment: yeahh its working Thank you so much @enwink sir you made my day thanks alot for this adorable help :)

Comment: i have one more query can we store the page content  in any variable after clicking on button, actually i need the data from processed page with simple dom

Comment: you're welcome, if it solved please mark the answer as correct. yes you can using `$driver->getPageSource()` but wait until the content rendered.

Comment: yes working fairly ,@ewwink it gives me home page but i need the content of page that comes after clicking what to do for this

Comment: please create new question I will try to help

Comment: i think we are very close to do it we just need the data from page that comes after button clicking could you please help me.. thanks

Comment: yess done this was the game of time and we have to wait for some time and after that particular time instance $driver will be updated with new page source

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium webdriver and **want to get image from page**, but blocked by **cors**.
You can just **say Selenium to go to image url** and after that **take screenshot**.
And your image will be saved!
And cors will not be a problem.
Here is example code in PHP:

```
$img_url = '.../6028384213.jpg';    
$driver->get($img_url);
$driver->takeScreenshot('img.png');
```

Your image will be opened by browser and after that saved to your local computer!